# How to dump list to Google Cloud Storage without creating in-memory dump?

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-cloud-storage

I have a big list of dicts, which occupies hundreds of MBs. I want to save this list to GCS and then read it in a different process. Initially, I tried to save `json.dumps(big_list)`, but that resulted in out of memory issues because the memory consumption is now twice of the memory of `big_list`. I want to use `json.dump(big_list, filename)`, but I don't think that is possible with GCS. I guess writing to CSV would be another option, but again I guess it's not easy to do without creating another stream in memory which will have the same data as `big_list`.

Let's say I have 300 MB in `big_list`. I want to save its content to GCS without increasing the memory to 600 MB because the limit on the instance is 512 MB.

Comment: Save it to a file (one dict per line) then read the file line by line using `json.loads(line)`,  then you remove the large JSON object from your stack. Would that work? Or does the whole thing need to go to google at one time?

Comment: I considered that as a last resort. In my use case a dict might not make a lot of sense, but I consider saving slices of the lists.Thanks for the advise, in case if I don't manage to save the entire file efficiently, I'll go with that approach.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you'll need to go a little more low-level than the cloud library.

The [Google API client libraries](https://googleapis.github.io/google-resumable-media-python/latest/google.resumable_media.requests.html#resumable-uploads) (as opposed to the [Google Cloud client libraries](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/index.html)) allows you to run resumable uploads by handling the data stream. This should allow you to only have a memory overhead as big as the chunk size that you want to use for the resumable upload (min 256Kb).

This works *in theory*, but I've been attempting to write some example code, and I'm totally failing due to my lack of knowledge about Python.

I've done resumable uploads by hand (using `curl`), and it's quite simple. You can check the step by step tutorial in [the GCS docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/resumable-upload).

If, with this idea, you're able to write working code, please share it!

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find detailed explanation about [Python Data Streaming to Google Cloud Storage with Resumable Uploads](https://dev.to/sethmlarson/python-data-streaming-to-google-cloud-storage-with-resumable-uploads-458h)

```
from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession
from google.resumable_media import requests, common
from google.cloud import storage

class GCSObjectStreamUpload(object):
    def __init__(
            self, 
            client: storage.Client,
            bucket_name: str,
            blob_name: str,
            chunk_size: int=256 * 1024
        ):
        self._client = client
        self._bucket = self._client.bucket(bucket_name)
        self._blob = self._bucket.blob(blob_name)

        self._buffer = b''
        self._buffer_size = 0
        self._chunk_size = chunk_size
        self._read = 0

        self._transport = AuthorizedSession(
            credentials=self._client._credentials
        )
        self._request = None  # type: requests.ResumableUpload

    def __enter__(self):
        self.start()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, *_):
        if exc_type is None:
            self.stop()

    def start(self):
        url = (
            f'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/'
            f'{self._bucket.name}/o?uploadType=resumable'
        )
        self._request = requests.ResumableUpload(
            upload_url=url, chunk_size=self._chunk_size
        )
        self._request.initiate(
            transport=self._transport,
            content_type='application/octet-stream',
            stream=self,
            stream_final=False,
            metadata={'name': self._blob.name},
        )

    def stop(self):
        self._request.transmit_next_chunk(self._transport)

    def write(self, data: bytes) -> int:
        data_len = len(data)
        self._buffer_size += data_len
        self._buffer += data
        del data
        while self._buffer_size >= self._chunk_size:
            try:
                self._request.transmit_next_chunk(self._transport)
            except common.InvalidResponse:
                self._request.recover(self._transport)
        return data_len

    def read(self, chunk_size: int) -> bytes:
        # I'm not good with efficient no-copy buffering so if this is
        # wrong or there's a better way to do this let me know! :-)
        to_read = min(chunk_size, self._buffer_size)
        memview = memoryview(self._buffer)
        self._buffer = memview[to_read:].tobytes()
        self._read += to_read
        self._buffer_size -= to_read
        return memview[:to_read].tobytes()

    def tell(self) -> int:
        return self._read


client = storage.Client()

with GCSObjectStreamUpload(client=client, bucket='test-bucket', blob='test-blob') as s:
    for _ in range(1024):
        s.write(b'x' * 1024)
```